# apollo-codegen output is empty

Tags: graphql

I'm running into a situation in which apollo-codegen is not successfully generating typescript code.

For the graphql file (`generated/schema.graphql`):

```
type Author {
  id: Int!
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  posts: [Post]
}

type Post {
  id: Int!
  title: String
  author: Author
  votes: Int
}
```

I then run :

`$apollo-codegen introspect-schema generated/schema.graphql --output generated/schema.json`

this generates a `./generated/schema.json` that appears to contain the relevant information (I see information about Author and its properties, and Post and its properties).

I then run

`$apollo-codegen generate generated/schema.graphql  --schema generated/schema.json --target typescript` and get an (effectively) empty output.

```
//  This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.
/* tslint:disable */
/* tslint:enable */
```

I've tried generating .swift files as well, with similar empty output.

Apollo codegen version is:

```
"apollo-codegen": "^0.11.2",
```

Anyone see if what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a collaborator on `apollo-codegen`. Happy to hear that you're giving it a try!

You're not seeing any output because **apollo-codegen generates types based on the GraphQL operations (query, mutation) in your project -- not based solely on the types in your schema.**

In our experience, it's very rare that you would send a query for a full GraphQL type. Instead, we have found types based on graphql operations to be the most useful.

For instance, given the types you've provided, you might write a query:

```
query AuthorQuery {
  authors {
    firstName,
    lastName
  }
}
```

The type that would get generated (and that you'd probably want to use in code that consumes the results of this query, is

```
type AuthorQuery = {
  authors: Array<{
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string
  }>
}
```

Notice how you would use the `AuthorQuery` type in your React component (or similar) whereas you wouldn't use an `Author` type since it would include more fields than you've actually requested.

If you do however have a use-case for a 1:1 type from your graphql schema to typescript, do file an issue on the project itself and I'd be happy to discuss there :)

Comment: I tried this, but it looks like it gets filtered when I generate the schema.  Could you take a look?  https://github.com/benjaminabbitt/graphql-experiments

Comment: I had trouble understanding this too since the example is "--output scema.ts" but what is in fact outputted are the query types, not the schema types. Perhaps naming the output file "query-types.ts" in the example would make it clearer.

Comment: Do you have any doc on what is in that `.graphql` file ?